# How to create File from list of byte arrays in Android?

Tags: java, android, webrtc, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I am trying to transfer a .mp4 file using `WebRTC` and it's `DataChannel`. In order to do that I am breaking the file into chunks like below:

```
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] chunk = new byte[260000];
int chunkLen = 0;
sentFileByte = new ArrayList<>();
while ((chunkLen = is.read(chunk)) != -1) {
    sentFileByte.add(chunk);
}
```

After that, sending the chunks by index like:

```
byte[] b = sentFileByte.get(index);
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(b);
bb.put(b);
bb.flip();
dataChannel.send(new DataChannel.Buffer(bb, true));
```

On the receiver end I am receiving the chunks and adding it to an Arraylist

```
receivedFileByteArr.add(chunkByteArr);
```

After receiving all the chunks successfully I am trying to convert these in to a file like below:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName;
File file = new File(path);
try {
     FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
     for (int i = 0; i < receivedFileByteArr.size(); i++) {
         fileOutputStream.write(receivedFileByteArr.get(i));
     }
     fileOutputStream.close();
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

After completing all these steps, file is created successfully. File size is also same. But problem is the file is not playable in any video player. I guess I am making some mistake on `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream`. I need help to fix this error.

Comment: It makes no sense what you do. Why all this?  Send the file in one piece. Do away with that arraylist to begin with. Instead of adding a chunck to that arraylist write it directly to the outputstream.

Comment: `sentFileByte.add(chunk);` This was already no good as you did not use chunckLen. It should have been sentFileByte.add(chunk, 0, chunkLen);.